# Finding highest value of variable

Tags: bash, awk

So i am trying to find the highest value of the variable. For example o have this:

```
var1=14
var2=15
var3=16
```

I want to find the biggest value which is var 3 and save it somewhere. Is there a way to do that?

Something like this:

```
tmp=`sort -n $var1 $var2 $var3  ` (this is an example)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find the max, by the variable **names**

```
#!/bin/bash

maxvarname() {
    for i; do
        echo "${!i} $i"
    done | sort -nr | sed -n '1s/.* \(.*\)/\1/p'
}

#MAIN

#the variables
var1=14
var2=15
var3=16

vname=$(maxvarname var1 var2 var3) #note, arguments are the NAMES (not values e.g. $var1) - without $
echo "Max value is in the variable named: '$vname' and its value is: ${!vname}"
```

it prints:

```
Max value is in the variable named: 'var3' and its value is: 16
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to get those numbers into an array, from there it's just:

```
a=(14 15 16) # Example array

IFS=$'\n'
echo "${a[*]}" | sort -nr | head -n1
```

Comment: Not that I can see. They'd have to be in the same array to find the largest. Why CAN'T you use an array?

Answer (score 1):

```
max=$(echo $var{1,2,3} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -nr | head -1)
```

Comment: Better: `max=$(printf '%d\n $var{1,2,3} | sort -nr | head -1)`

Answer (score 1):

Check below solution if you want to find the maximum value of a variable -

```
$ cat f
var4=18
var1=14
var2=15
var3=16
$ max=$(sort -t'=' -nrk2 f|head -1)
$ echo $max
var4=18
```